# Why is $p_x = \mathcal I_V \left ( \{(x_1,x_2, \dots ,x_n) \} \right )$ a prime ideal?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, maximal-and-prime-ideals

Let $L$ be a field and $K$ be a subfield of $L.$ Let $V$ be an affine variety in $\Bbb A^n (L).$ Then the coordinate ring $K[V]$ is defined by

$$K[V] = \frac {K[X_1,X_2, \dots ,X_n]} {\mathcal I(V)}$$

where $\mathcal I(V)$ is the vanishing ideal of $V.$ Now for any $(x_1,x_2,\dots,x_n) \in V$ set $p_x = \mathcal I_V \left ( \{(x_1,x_2, \dots,x_n) \} \right)$ the set of all functions $\varphi \in K[V]$ such that $\varphi (x_1,x_2, \dots, x_n) = 0.$ **Then $p_x$ is a prime ideal $\ne K[V]$.**

I don't understand the last sentence in bold letters mentioned in the lecture notes given by our instructor. Why is $p_x$ a prime ideal of $K[V]$? Let us take two functions $\varphi,\psi \in K[V]$ such that $\varphi \psi \in p_x.$ Then $\exists$ $f,g \in K[X_1,X_2, \cdots ,X_n]$ such that $\varphi = f + \mathcal {I} (V)$ and $\psi = g + \mathcal {I} (V).$ Since $\varphi \psi (x_1,x_2, \cdots, x_n) = 0$ so we have $(fg)(x_1,x_2, \cdots, x_n) \in \mathcal {I} (V).$ Therefore $f(x_1,x_2, \cdots, x_n) \cdot g(x_1,x_2, \cdots , x_n) \in \mathcal {I} (V).$ We have to show that either $f(x_1,x_2, \cdots , x_n) \in \mathcal {I} (V)$ or $g(x_1,x_2, \cdots , x_n) \in \mathcal {I} (V).$ Since $f(x_1,x_2,\cdots , x_n) \cdot g(x_1,x_2, \cdots , x_n)$ is a constant function belonging to the vanishing ideal $\mathcal I (V)$ so we must have $f(x_1,x_2,\cdots , x_n) \cdot g(x_1,x_2, \cdots , x_n) = 0.$ Since $f(x_1,x_2,\cdots , x_n),g(x_1,x_2, \cdots , x_n) \in K$ and $K$ is a field so we must have either $f(x_1,x_2,\cdots , x_n) = 0$ or  $g(x_1,x_2,\cdots , x_n) = 0.$ So either $\varphi \in \mathcal {I} (V)$ or $\psi \in \mathcal {I} (V).$ So if we can show that $p_x \subsetneq K[V]$ we are through. But how can I show that?

Please help me in this regard. Thank you very much.

Comment: If $V$ is a variety in $\mathbf{A}^n(L)$ then its coordinate ring should have coefficients in $L$, not $K$. Actually I don't understand why you have both $L$ and $K$.

Comment: I just write an element of $\frac {K[X_1,X_2, \cdots , X_n]} {\mathcal {I} (V)}.$ I have used that result from Kunz's **Algebraic Geometry.**

Comment: Your title asks why $p_x$ is a prime ideal but your question seems to be why is $p_x \ne K[V]$. So which is it?

Comment: Why is the downvote?

Comment: @Trevor Gunn both are actually my question. The motivation behind posting this question here is to check whether my answer holds good or not. Thank you very much.

Comment: Hint: is $1$ in your ideal?

Comment: Which ideal do you talk about? Do you talk about $p_x$? What is $1$ here? Is it the function which sends every $(x_1,x_2, \cdots , x_n) \in \Bbb A^n(L)$ to $1$ @KReiser?

Comment: Would you please check whether $\varphi = (X_1+X_2+\cdots+X_n-a +1) + \mathcal {I} (V)$ will work well or not? where $x_1+x_2+ \cdots +x_n = a.$

Comment: I'm talking about $p_x\subset K[V]$, like your question is. And $1$ is the element $1\in K[V]$ which is the function that returns $1$ on all points of $V$. For your followup comment, what if your variety $V$ is given by the zero set of $1+\sum X_i$? Then your choice wouldn't work. Pick the easiest thing you can get away with: $1$.

Comment: Can $1 \in \mathcal {I} (V)$? For otherwise $\mathcal {I} (V) = K[X_1,X_2, \cdots, X_n].$ Which is not true.

Comment: What happens if $1 \in \mathcal{I}(V)$? What does that make $V$?

Comment: How can $1 \in \mathcal {I} (V)$ if the underlying field is infinite? Because $V$ is the common solution of finitely many polynomials in $X_1,X_2, \cdots , X_n$ over $K.$ Take one such. Call it $f.$ Then $V$ is a subset of the $K$-hypersurface generated by $f.$ But we know that if the underlying field $L$ is infinite then outside any $K$-hypersurface there are infinitely many points of $\Bbb A^n (L).$ Take one such let's say $(x_1,x_2,\cdots, x_n).$ Then the polynomial $X_1 - x_1 \in K[X_1,X_2, \cdots , X_n] \setminus \mathcal {I} (V).$

Comment: What are you talking about? It should be as easy as asking "does $1=0$ on $V$?" which is an obvious no if $V$ is nonempty.

Comment: I think $1 \in \mathcal {I} (V)$ implies whether $1=0$ on $K$ if $V$ was non-empty. Which cannot be true since $K$ is a field.

Comment: What will be $\mathcal {I} (V)$ if $V$ is empty?